# Is there a "best" area in Queensland's Sunshine Coast for currency exchanges?

Tags: money, australia, exchange, queensland, sunshine-coast

In other countries I find tourist areas have more money changers and thus greater competition and more competitive rates.

The Sunshine Coast generally is a tourist area but is also very suburban, spread out, and car oriented.

Also there's probably certain parts that attract more foreign tourists, which is where FOREX stalls tend to be.

Would Noosa Heads be best, or some other area?

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine you'd find something in the main touristy area, like Noosa Heads/Noosa Junction. Also, Sunshine Plaza in Maroochydore would be a good bet, although it's a bit of a drive. It's one of the bigger shopping malls in the Sunshine Coast region, so it might have better competition re: exchange rates.

I've also heard that some banks, like Suncorp, will do foreigh currency exchange, but i can't vouch for the quality of their rates.

Comment: Yes I'm based in Minyama, Mooloolaba, so not far from Sunshine Plaza. Google Maps showed two exchange places there but I actually found three. So not a bad start. Rates varied by a much larger amount between the three than expected and all were worse than in the airport in Kuala Lumpur which was much worse than Chinatown in KL (-: I'll check Noosa Heads/Junction in the coming days if nobody else does.